# How to add handlers to Excel Calculate Events with ExcelDNA

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I would like to be able to listen to the BeginCalculate and EndCalculate events for all sheets in Excel from my ExcelDNA addin, and execute some intialization code. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some discussion on the [Excel-DNA Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/exceldna) here: https://groups.google.com/group/exceldna/browse_frm/thread/58da470968d6658b This shows how to handle the C API ON.RECALC event, which fires after a recalculation.

You can get also hold of the Excel Application COM object with a call to `ExcelDnaUtil.Application`, and then register your event handlers for the Application events. The Application events are documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj734018.aspx and you might be interested in `AfterCalculate`.

I don't know of any Excel events that fire *before* recalculation.